# LINQ unexpected behavior when returning IEnumerable and calling ToArray

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

I noticed some weird behavior in LINQ-code, and reduced the problem to the following minimal example with two methods:

```
IA Find(string n)
{
    IA result;
    if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue(n, out result))
    {
        throw Exception();
    }
    return result;
}

IEnumerable<IA> Find(IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    return names.Select(Find).ToArray();
}
```

This works as expected.

Now, I remove the .ToArray() so the method looks as follows:

```
IEnumerable<IA> Find(IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    return names.Select(Find);
}
```

This change will cause the exception not to be thrown, even if some of the names are not found in _dictionary, but are present in the names parameter.

What causes this (to me) unexpected behavior of LINQ?

Comment: Deferred execution.  You are not iterating the results when you do a Select.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its because of deferred execution. The Linq is not evaluated until you execute it.

The call to `ToArray()` causes a full enumeration of the `IEnumerable` and thus, the exception to occur.

The second method does not enumerate the `IEnumerable` and execution is deferred until the caller needs it.

---

If you were to enumerate the result of `Find` e.g.

```
var result = Find(new[] { "name" }).ToList();
```

or

```
foreach (var found in Find(new[] { "name" }))
{
    ...
}
```

then the exception would occur.